# Reporting Library for ASP.NET MVC (2)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, reporting

We have a portal which our customers reach and get some datas. We are looking a creative solutions for reporting, which will be embedded to our web application.

Platform : ASP.NET MVC2, fluent nHibernate, mysql and hosted on amazon

Open Source: preferred but also can be commercial

Handle large amounts of data: Not too much

Large numbers of concurrent users: Up to 50-100

Export options : excel, pdf prefferred

I looked at the following libraries:
http://www.syncfusion.com/products/whatsnew/user-interface-edition/aspnet-mvc
http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/asp-net-mvc.xml
http://demos.telerik.com/reporting/sales-dashboard/demo.aspx

The crutial thing is I have to find and decide a library, because of we are on production env. this should be final decision.

Comment: Have you considered using SQL Server Reporting Services?

Comment: Do you recommend SQL Server Reporting Services ? As you read our platform database is mysql.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. If you had SSRS, it could consume MySQL data, I think. Just licensing question left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use Telerik Reporting which is very easy to use.
You just design your report and pass your model to report (it can be object data source, entity data source, sql datasource etc).

You just pay one time.
Exporting options is also enough (excel, pdf, word etc)